# Изменение цвета кнопки button при заполнении полей text и password

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой код

```
<form class = "layer1" name = "form">
      <input type = "text" name = "telephonenumber" maxlength="10" class = "login" >
        <input type = "password" name = "password" value = "" 
        placeholder="Пароль" class = "password">
        <button class = "grnd" name ="button" >
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы при заполнении полей логина и пароля , изменялся цвет кнопки ,соответственно , если весь текст будет удален из этих полей , чтобы кнопка принимала прежний вид. Хочу сделать на чисто js , но если честно не понимаю как.

Comment: :placeholder-shown https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown Но лучше сделать плэйсхолдер самому, через span, это даст большую кроссбраузерность.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, при чем тут placeholder, в чем идея?

Comment: @Air показал пример в ответе...

Answer (score 2):

```js
var pass = document.querySelector('.password');
var login = document.querySelector('.login');


pass.addEventListener('input', changeBackground);
login.addEventListener('input', changeBackground);

function changeBackground() {
  if (pass.value !== '' && login.value !== '') {
    document.querySelector('button').style.background = 'green';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('button').style.background = 'red';
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<form class="layer1" name="form">
  <input type="text" name="telephonenumber" maxlength="10" class="login" />
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Пароль" class="password" />
  <button class="grnd" name="button">button</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
input:placeholder-shown+input:placeholder-shown+button,
input:placeholder-shown+button {
  background-color: red;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown)+input:not(:placeholder-shown)+button {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<form class="layer1" name="form">
  <input type="text" name="telephonenumber" maxlength="10" class="login" placeholder="Логин">
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Пароль" class="password">
  <button class="grnd" name="button">Lorem</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо проверять когда поле теряет фокус,для этого подписаться на событие `blur`,
пример:

```
var fieldLogin = document.querySelector('.login');
fieldLogin.addEventListener('blur', function(){
  if(!fieldLogin.value.length) alert('few');
});
```